# how to prevent store proxy to run in extjs 4 mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am having one problem in which i want to prevent the ***read* proxy of the store to execute in extJs 4.0.2a mvc

my taskStore is defined as below

```
var taskStore = Ext.create("Gnt.data.TaskStore", {
    model: 'gantt.model.Task',
    proxy       : {
        type : 'ajax',
        method: 'GET',
        api: {
            read:       'task/GetTask.action',
            create:     'task/CreateTask.action',
            destroy:    'task/DeleteTask.action',
            update:     'task/UpdateTask.action'
        },
        writer : new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
            root : 'taskdata',
            encode : true,
            writeAllFields : true
        }),
        reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            totalPropery: 'total',
            successProperty : 'success',
            idProperty : 'id',
            type : 'json',
            root: function (o) {
                if (o.taskdata) {
                    return o.taskdata;
                } else {
                    return o.children;
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

now I want to restrict the **read** proxy defined in it to execute on the view creation. I want to call another ajax request on the view creation. I tried but not able to succeed.

Help me to solve my problem, so i can move forwar. Any idea all suggestion welcomed.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add `autoload: false` to your store definition and call `taskStore.load({ /* your configuration here for a one-off load */ });` whenever you want